# Accessing LivePerson real-time chat data

Tags: web-applications, liveperson

I was wondering if anyone of you had any experience with developing for LivePerson.

We're developing a WebApp that should integrate with LivePerson. The app should retrieve the text data sent by customer (customer's message etc) during real-time chat session.

My question, is it possible to get customer's message data in real-time. If yes, what resources should we be looking.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible mostly for security. You can hook into an on event in the config to know when a message is sent or received but not the contents

```
var _LP_CFG_ = {
app_id: appId,
options: {
    triggerSelector: '.chat-btn',
    onReady: function () {
        LPMobile.on('visitorMessage', function (data) {
            // do something
        });
        LPMobile.on('agentMessage', function(data) {
            // do something
        })
    }
}
};
```